# Fragment in LinearLayout changes its height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to set very simple thing in XML in android app.

I want to put fragment in top of every activity, and trying to divide screen into 2/8 weight (sum 10). But unfortunately this is changing from activity to activity. No idea why. Any help? :)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="top" >

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        class="com.app.TopFragment" />

<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:id="@+id/chart_scrollview" >   

Here goes LinearLayout with other linearlayouts inside.

</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Fragment class declaration is:

```
class TopFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{}
```

EDIT2:
Thank you guys. Funny thing is that I already tried this 0dip thing and it was not working. Now it's working, but for any other people fighting similar problem here's the hint: Do not use

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

on anything which is inside of these things in my sample code. Always use

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

This was the reason why 0dip solution was not working. Thank you very much.

Comment: is the fragment a custom class like `myFragment extends Fragment`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="top" >

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            class="com.app.TopFragment" />

    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:id="@+id/chart_scrollview" >   

   <!-- Here goes LinearLayout with other linearlayouts inside-->

    </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing height of fragment and ScrollView from `wrap_content` to `match_parent` or `0dip` if you want to control the height of the views by their weights.

Answer (score 0):

then you should write something like this in your xml

```
<com.app.TopFragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    class="com.app.TopFragment" />
```